# Check if last character is a hyphen (-) in data annotation

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

What I want to do is throw a validation error message if the string entered does not have a hyphen (`-`) at the end in my MVC model.

I need to create a custom regex for it. This is what I have so far,

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required.")]
[Remote("CheckExistingUserName", "Home", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Username already exists.")]
[RegularExpression("^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?\-)+$", ErrorMessage = "Username is invalid.")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: That seems strange.  But why can't you just add it to the end of your regex? `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?)+\-$`

Comment: If the hyphen at the end was meant to be some sort of secret, I've got bad news for you...

Comment: Your pattern should be [`^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?)+-$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3a%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b%5cs%3f)%2b-%5cr%3f%24&i=aaA+000zzZ-%0d%0aaaA+000zzZ&o=m), not `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?\-)+$`. Basically, you can use `^.*-$` to require the last  char to be a hyphen. What requirements should your regex meet?

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?\-)+$` requires a `-` after each alphanumeric chunk.

You need to put it outside of the group, next to `$`:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?)+-$
                     ^
```

See the [online demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B%5Cs%3F)%2B-%5Cr%3F%24&i=aaA%20000zzZ-%0D%0AaaA%20000zzZ&o=m)

This way, you require a string to end with `-` and the whole pattern now matches:

- `^` - the start of a string
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?)+` - 1 or more sequences of

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters or digits
  - `\s?` - 1 or 0 whitespaces
- `-` - a hyphen
- `$` - end of string.

Note that a bit more optimal pattern (from the regex engine point of view) will be

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*-$
```

as it is more linear. See [its demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b(%3f%3a%5cs%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b)*-%5cr%3f%24&i=aaA+000zzZ-%0d%0aaaA+000zzZ&o=m).